# How do directives control each other?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives:

```
module.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: "/templates/ui/components/modal.htm",
        replace: true,
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("Loaded modal directive.");
        },
        controller: function ($rootScope, $scope) {
            $scope.isOpen = false;

            $scope.open = function () {
                $scope.isOpen = true;
            };

            $scope.close = function () {
                $scope.isOpen = false;
            };

            // Global
            $rootScope.$on('openModal', function () {
                console.log("open"); // How to call open function here?
            });
            $rootScope.$on('closeModal', function () {
                console.log("close"); // How to call close function here?
            });
        }
    }
});

module.directive('popUpWindow', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: "/templates/ui/components/pop-up-window.htm",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("Loaded pop-up window directive.");
            $scope.title = attrs["title"];
        },
        controller: function ($rootScope, $scope) {
            $scope.isOpen = false;
            $scope.open = function () {
                $scope.isOpen = true;
                $rootScope.$emit('openModal');
            };
            $scope.close = function () {
                $scope.isOpen = false;
                $rootScope.$emit('closeModal');
            };
        }
    }
});
```

The idea is that there is only ever one modal for all possible instances of `popUpWindow`.

I have no idea how to get these two to talk to each other. How do I get hold of my modal and call it's open and close functions? Where should I put the open and close functions, controller or link? It seems like the controller but the link has access to `element`.. Should I be looking to get an instance of the modal or is there some neat Angular way of doing this?

I've got a function on the modal firing using $emit on the pop up window but this doesn't feel like a great way of communicating between directives.

I've trawled the net and tried a lot of stuff but not found anything that seems to fix this. It doesn't seem obvious.

Comment: Use a controller scope variable and watch it from both directives. If it's true display one, if it's false display the other.

Comment: So in a large project - say a CMS - I need to have a controller watching every single possible pop up window? Seems like a really convoluted way to achieve something incredibly simple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directives are a way to teach HTML new tricks and it is primarily used for creating some reusable HTML components, hence the functionality of a directive should be self-contained and it should be independent on other directives.

If you want to maintain multiple popup windows, for instance, you should make the popupWindow directive to be driven by the model passed in. And in your controller, you should be able to track all popupWindows by tracking the model.

Directives should talk to each other via controller though you can make it happen by using message broadcasting.

Hope it can shed some light on.

Comment: Yep, you're correct. I see that now. I was attempting to make angular work in line with my current javascript, and not as it should be. Having spent the day working out how controllers communicate to directives and what directives actually are it makes so much sense. The separation is beautiful. These videos really helped me understand that: http://www.egghead.io/